# Python parsing datetime string with IANA timezone info and turn it into a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I looking for a way to parse DateTime strings to DateTime object supporting timezones. as I understand in de documentations of `pytz`, `dateutil` and `maya` I can set up the time zone to my DateTime but the behavior is that the provided DateTime is recomputed to the introduced timezone, and what I need is an object representation of that DateTime with its timezone.

Using `luxon.js` as example of what I need but in python:

```
var keepZone = DateTime.fromFormat(
                   "2017-05-15T09:10:23 Europe/Paris",
                   "yyyy-MM- dd'T'HH:mm:ss z", 
                   {setZone: true}
               );

keepZone.zoneName;   //=> 'Europe/Paris'
keepZone.toString(); //=> '2017-05-15T09:10:23.000+02:00'
```

Comment: is your datetime string alsways in this format?

Comment: @MrFuppes isn't decided yet, but once we decide the format it will be always the same, and for sure I will always use IANA timezone format, so this can be a very good example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a format like this (ISO format datetime + IANA tz name), you can simply split on space, convert the first part to datetime with `fromisoformat` and set the time zone by replacing the `tzinfo`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

s = "2017-05-15T09:10:23 Europe/Paris"
parts = s.split(' ')

dt = datetime.fromisoformat(parts[0]).replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz(parts[1]))

print(dt)
>>> 2017-05-15 09:10:23+02:00
print(repr(dt))
>>> datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 15, 9, 10, 23, tzinfo=tzfile('Europe/Paris'))
```

Note that

- with a timezone object obtained from `pytz`, you need to [`localize`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic)
- if you use Python 3.9, you don't need a third party library at all since you have [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard lib.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was reading about `.replace` right now but I didn't find a good way to use the IANA string, in python < 3.9. I also find a backport of that https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/

Comment: @efirvida: jep, backports.zoneinfo is also nice (I'd even prefer that over implementing dateutil now). But in contrast to pytz, dateutil uses the same semantics as zoneinfo, so that should be fine as well I think.